# Python-CSV-writerow: Errors occurred

Tags: python, csv

I wrote following code, and it causes errors:

- `price = item.find('span', "sx-zero-spacing'").text`, this line causes an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
- it did create a file named as "scraper_data.csv", however, when I open the file, it's empty and there is no any data inside.
- in addition, when I run the above .py file again, another error occurred, `csvfile = open('scraper_data_csv', 'a') PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'scraper_data_csv'`

Any help or suggestion please! Thank you!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/?field-keywords=horse+head+mask"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

items = soup.find_all("li", "s-result-item")

csvfile = open('scraper_data.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

for item in items:
    name = item.find('h2').text
    price = item.find('span', "sx-zero-spacing'").text
    writer.writerow([name, price])
```

Comment: Well, your second ``item.find`` is failing to find anything - you need to fix that.  I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but the unmatched single quote in that second parameter looks suspicious...  The error on rerunning the program is probably because the file is still open for writing.

Comment: Thanks jason, yeppp, I fixed the single quote. As you mentioned, the fill is still open for writing, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Read up on the ``with`` statement - if used when opening the file, it can guarantee the file gets closed, even if an error occurs.

Comment: Do you have the csv file open in Excel? It's very jealous when it has a file open and won't let anyone else near it, even to just look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `open`, try `with open`, which automatically closes the file at the end of the block. Also, use `try` / `except` to catch items with no `sx-zero-spacing`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/?field-keywords=horse+head+mask'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('li', 's-result-item')

with open('scraper_data.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for item in items:
        try:
            name = item.find('h2').text
            price = item.find('span', 'sx-zero-spacing').text
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        writer.writerow([name, price])
```